# How to set FTP encryption value

Tags: ftp

I unable to connect with server using FTP (Filezila).

I got this error : Response: **421 Sorry, cleartext sessions are not accepted on this server**.
While goggle, i got response like choose "FTP over TLS which is encrypted".
I can see FTP over TLS in FTP site manager encryption dropdown
But, where should i give encryption value in FTP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adrian mentioned, you need to set FileZilla to use an encrypted connection when talking to this FTP server.

Quoting from the [FileZilla wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/SSL/TLS):

> For a client to connect to a server using SSL, then the host for that connection needs to be set to FTPS. In FileZilla client this means prefixing the host with "FTPES://" for "explicit" FTPS, or "FTPS://" for the legacy "implicit" FTPS.
>
> FTPS (SSL/TLS) is served up in two incompatible modes. If using explicit FTPS, the client connects to the normal FTP port and explicitly switches into secure (SSL/TLS) mode with "AUTH TLS", whereas implicit FTPS is an older style service that assumes SSL/TLS mode right from the start of the connection (and normally listens on TCP port 990, rather than 21). In a FileZilla client this means prefixing the host with "FTPES://" to connect an "explicit" FTPS server, or "FTPS://" for the legacy "implicit" server (for which you will likely also need to set the port to 990).

Depending on how the server was configured, one of these two settings should work:

- `ftpes://` on port 21
- `ftps://` on port 990

Answer (score 1):

FTP is not an encrypted protocol. Some network admin is telling you to switch to an encrypted protocol such as SFTP.